# Is it possible to define a Spring Repository for shared classes?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a class `User` which is shared between the server and the android client. So I don't want to annotate the class with an `@id` annotation.

What is the best way to deal with this in spring-jpa?

Comment: if user is an entity class then it should have an id irrespective of the client as it is not a value object rather it is a persistable entity.

Comment: Sharing entities is probably a bad idea: they map your database, and the client shouldn't care about that. But loading a class with annotations that are not in the classpath doesn't cause any problem, so if you really want to, you can.

Comment: @Barath it has an Id but i don't want to annotate it

Comment: @JBNizet you're totally right with it being a bad idea. But I am converting a legacy application to spring-boot and need to get it working before I do the refactoring. ;-) I did not think about the annotations won't matter.

Comment: @n3utrino then in that case define a repository with `@NoRepositoryBean` annotation not to be picked up by JpaRepositories and provide the repository class implementing the jparepository. Its a hard way though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the simplest possible way is to fallback to `xml` mapping so your domain objects will stay pure.

Spring-boot will notice that you're using this type of mapping and configure hibernate for you out of the box.

Here is a simple example:

```
package com.stackoverflow.so45264894;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class So45264894Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So45264894Application.class, args);
    }

    public static class User {
        private Long   id;
        private String username;

        public Long getId() { return id; }
        public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

        public String getUsername() { return username; }
        public void setUsername(String username) { this.username = username; }
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner run(UserRepository userRepository) {
        final User user = new User();
        user.setUsername("admin");
        return args -> userRepository.save(user);
    }
}

interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<So45264894Application.User, Long> {
}
```

And mapping from `/src/main/resources/com/stackoverflow/so45264894/User.hbm.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="com.stackoverflow.so45264894" default-access="field">
    <class name="com.stackoverflow.so45264894.So45264894Application$User" table="users" dynamic-update="true">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="user_id" sql-type="integer"/>
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <property name="username" column="username" unique="true"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Output:

```
Hibernate: drop table users if exists
Hibernate: create table users (user_id integer generated by default as identity, username varchar(255), primary key (user_id))
Hibernate: alter table users add constraint UK_r43af9ap4edm43mmtq01oddj6 unique (username)
Hibernate: insert into users (username, user_id) values (?, ?) // <- this is userRepository.save() call
```